# How to get a specific string in array using powershell?

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have a text file. The text file contain of this

```
Name(0x0)/Class(0x17,0x0)/Format(0x0,0xFFFF,0x0)
```

I want to get this string only `Format(0x0,0xFFFF,0x0)`

I try to split it and get the array number. BUT THE PROBLEM is this format text file sometime change. This string `Format(0x0,0xFFFF,0x0)` NOT always in the last array, and the total of array sometime different as well. like this.

```
Name(0x0)/Class(0x17,0x0)/Class2(0000,0000)/Format(0x0,0xFFFF,0x0)
or
Name(0x0)/Class(0x17,0x0)/Format(0x0,0xFFFF,0x0)/Class2(0000,0000)
```

My expectation, I can get this string `Format(0x0,0xFFFF,0x0)` , wherever it's place. 
Anyone can help me please. Thanks a lot.

```
$File = Get-Content .\PC.txt
$split = $File -split "/"
$found= $split[2]
$found
```

Comment: Use a [Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) with e.g. [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [iRon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58948598/45375) suggests, you can use [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) with a [regular expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions) as follows:

```
(Select-String 'Format\(.+?\)' .\PC.txt).Matches.Value
```

The `.Matches.Value` part extracts what the regular expression `Format\(.+?\)` matched from each selected line in file `.\PC.txt`, via the [`[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo) instances that `Select-Object` outputs.

A simpler solution will be possible once [the `-OnlyMatching` switch](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/10696) gets implemented, which directly outputs only the matching parts of selected lines.

```
# Upcoming feature, not yet implemented as of PowerShell Core 7.0.0-preview.5
Select-String 'Format\(.+?\)' .\PC.txt -OnlyMatching
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this simple way as well

```
$File = Get-Content .\PC.txt
$split = $File -split "/"
$found = $split -like "*Format*"
```

it works for me.